# PHP & Mysql - nested loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables - products and productimages.
product has unique id and title.
productimages has productid and imageurl. these are examples of my tables:

**products:**

```
|id|title    |
_____________
|1 |Laptop   |
|2 |Speakers |
```

**productimages:**

```
|productid|imageurl|
___________________
|    1    |lap1.png|
|    1    |lap2.png|
|    1    |lap3.png|
|    2    |spe1.png|
```

Right now I have a nested loop in PHP.
loop through all rows of -> `select * from products`
and for every product inside the loop -> `select * from productimages where productid = id` which is basically another loop inside the first loop.

and then I take all productimages into array and decode to JSON [title,photos].

Now imagine you have 2 million rows in productimages, the query times are too high, is there any way to make it more efficient?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id LIMIT 10;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $response = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $photos = array();
        $id = $row["id"];
        $title = $row["title"];         

        $queryp = "select imageurl from productimages where productid= '".$id."';";
        $resultp = mysqli_query($con,$queryp);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($resultp)>0)
        {
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultp)) {
                $photourl = $row2["imageurl"];
                array_push($photos,$photourl);
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Where is code of LOOP you have tried?

Comment: You may not need to take all the rows. You can use "limit" and "pagination" for display data. And for loading images, you can use "lazy load" of jquery

Comment: You could start with a JOIN so you only run 1 query

Comment: But do you really want to show 2,000,000 products all in one page. No. So you had better incorporate some pagination as well

Comment: select * from products,productimages where products.id = productimages.productid

Comment: @RaviHirani A JOIN would be better

Comment: @Hassaan I just added the code.

Comment: @Arun This php code is a communication between an android app to mysql database

Comment: Looks like you have some way to go to get this code to work properly. Currently you are only putting the photos somewhere in an array, the product names get totally forgotten about

Comment: @RiggsFolly 
No, this is only half of the code, the rest handles decoding the data to JSON format

Answer (score 1):

Some betterment for you could be:

1) Don't use `select *`. Use column names instead. e.g. `select products.id, products.title, productimages.imageurl`

2) Use `JOIN` instead of nested loop

So, you can try querying data like:

```
select products.id, products.title, productimages.imageurl
from products
join productimages on products.id = productimages.productid
ORDER BY products.id LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It does work, but query times didn't change. it took 9 seconds to execute before, and it's the same now with this code.

Comment: @FiverrAnimation query speed optimization is not only dependent upon the way you form your query. It also depends upon database normalization, table indexing, even sometimes some of the server parameters, the environment your database and application running on etc. So you have to consider these all factors to count the query execution time

Comment: The thing is that without the nested loop, the query takes 0.5 seconds, and with the nested loop it takes 9 seconds. So it leaves us with only 1 option - the productimages is responsible for query delays

Answer (score 0):

This case is not uncommon - you have two tables in a one to many relationship.

You should never nest an SQL call in a loop if you can possibly avoid it but there is a decision to be made about one SQL call or two.

A single SQL call could be:

```
SELECT id, title, imageURL
  FROM products LEFT JOIN productImages ON id=productid
```

The disadvantage of this is that you are extracting the title several times for each product and this is wasteful.

Using two SQL statements you can download the titles once for each product:

```
SELECT id, title FROM products
```

The results of this query can be stored in an associative array - so that you can look up the title for each id.

The second query is:

```
SELECT productid, imageURL FROM productImages ORDER BY productid, imageURL
```

You can loop through the results of this query, spitting out the title as you go.

Answer (score 0):

To save the images with product you can add a column **`imageurl`** in the **products** table.collect the image names with `,` and insert that image name string to the **products** table.
your table looks like below.

```
 +--------------+--------------+---------------------------+
 |     id       |    title     | imageurl                  |
 +--------------+--------------+---------------------------+
 |      1       |  Laptop      | lap1.png,lap2.png,lap3.png|
 +--------------+--------------+---------------------------+
 |      2       |  Speakers    | spe1.png                  |
```

Hope you understood what i explain.